# using google-sign.in in a webapp: sign out using Sign-In button

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

The following webpage explains an easy workflow to integrate google sign-in into a webapp:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

After implementing the code, I am able to sign in using the "sign in" button, which shows "signed in" afterwards. How can I use this same button to sign out again? The linked tutorial only explains how to do that using a separate button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot use the same button for `sign-out` also. Instead you can add a `sign-out` button or link to your site and use the given `signOut()` function.